# Percentage discount based on user role and payment method in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I was trying to make a code snippet for functions.php which would apply a discount of 2 % for cart totals when the role "subscriber" and the payment method "credit-card" are both selected. My progress so far

```
function discount_when_role_and_payment(/* magic */) {
global $woocommerce;
if ( /* credit-card selected */ && current_user_can('subscriber') ) {
    /* get woocommerce cart totals, apply 2% discount and return*/
} 
return /*cart totals after discount*/;
}

add_filter( '/* magic */', 'discount_when_role_and_payment' );
```

Could anyone help complete this? Or atleast point to the right direction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code will apply a discount of 2% to cart when a targeted payment method has been selected by a subscriber user role only on checkout page:

```
// Applying conditionally a discount
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'discount_based_on_user_role_and_payment', 20, 1 );
function discount_based_on_user_role_and_payment( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return; // Exit

    // Only on checkout page for 'subscriber' user role
    if ( ! ( is_checkout() && current_user_can('subscriber') ) )
        return; // Exit

    // HERE Below define in the array your targeted payment methods IDs
    $targeted_payment_methods = array( 'paypal', 'stripe' );
    // HERE define the percentage discount
    $percentage = 2;

    if( in_array( WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method'), $targeted_payment_methods ) ){
        // Calculation
        $discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * $percentage / 100;
        // Applying discount
        $cart->add_fee( sprintf( __("Discount (%s)", "woocommerce"), $percentage . '%'), -$discount, true );
    }
}

// Refreshing totals on choseen payment method change event
add_action( 'woocommerce_review_order_before_payment', 'refresh_payment_methods' );
function refresh_payment_methods(){
    // Only on checkout page
    if ( ! ( is_checkout() && current_user_can('subscriber') ) ) return;
    // jQuery code
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
            $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', 'input[name^="payment_method"]', function() {
                $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
            });
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

This code goes on function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

[image]

> To get the correct desired **Payment methods IDs**, you will have to inspect the html code around the payment methods radio buttons searching with your browser inspector tools:
>
> [image]

Comment: You are using "add_fee" to add a discount, but documentation says "Do not enter negative amounts". It's true I can't find an add_discount method: https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/class-wc-cart.php#L1914

Comment: You can use "wp_enque_js" to add the Javascript code, I think this is the preferred method