# Apply a discount for a specific user role in Woocommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce, cart, user-roles, discount

I have a woocommerce store, with 3 user roles, I want to provide a 10% discount on the cart total only for a user role 'company'.

I found *"[Percentage discount based on user role and payment method in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51352055/percentage-discount-based-on-user-role-and-payment-method-in-woocommerce/51352908#51352908)"* answer that is very neer of what I need, but don't know how to modify the code to feet my needs, as it contains also a condition based on payment method and displaying the discount only at checkout, but I need it to display in cart as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following code will apply a 10% discount for 'company' user role (on cart and checkout):

```
// Applying conditionally a discount for a specific user role
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'discount_based_on_user_role', 20, 1 );
function discount_based_on_user_role( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return; // Exit

    // Only for 'company' user role
    if ( ! current_user_can('company') )
        return; // Exit

    // HERE define the percentage discount
    $percentage = 10;

    $discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * $percentage / 100; // Calculation

    // Applying discount
    $cart->add_fee( sprintf( __("Discount (%s)", "woocommerce"), $percentage . '%'), -$discount, true );
}
```

Code goes on *`functions.php`* file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: and if you want to exclude already discounted products (so apply just for the ones that have regular price)?

Answer (score 0):

Does anyone know how to include multiple user roles with different discount amounts to this code?

```
// Applying conditionally a discount for a specific user role
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'discount_based_on_user_role', 20, 1 );
function discount_based_on_user_role( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return; // Exit

    // Only for 'company' user role
    if ( ! current_user_can('company') )
        return; // Exit

    // HERE define the percentage discount
    $percentage = 10;

    $discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * $percentage / 100; // Calculation

    // Applying discount
    $cart->add_fee( sprintf( __("Discount (%s)", "woocommerce"), $percentage . '%'), -$discount, true );
}
```