# Set a minimum order amount in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, checkout

I want to have a minimum order amount in my WooCommerce store. The following code is perfectly showing a notice if the amount isn't reached but the checkout is still possible. How to disable checkout-button when the minimum amount isn't reached?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );

function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    // Set this variable to specify a minimum order value
    $minimum = 50;

    if ( WC()->cart->total < $minimum ) {

        if( is_cart() ) {

            wc_print_notice( 
                sprintf( 'Your current order total is %s — you must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order ' , 
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->total ), 
                    wc_price( $minimum )
                ), 'error' 
            );

        } else {

            wc_add_notice( 
                sprintf( 'Your current order total is %s — you must have an order with a minimum of %s to place your order' , 
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->total ), 
                    wc_price( $minimum )
                ), 'error' 
            );

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using the `woocommerce_check_cart_items` hook instead.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To set a minimum order amount you can use `woocommerce_check_cart_items` action hook this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'required_min_cart_subtotal_amount' );
function required_min_cart_subtotal_amount() {

    // HERE Set minimum cart total amount
    $minimum_amount = 250;

    // Total (before taxes and shipping charges)
    $cart_subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;

    // Add an error notice is cart total is less than the minimum required
    if( $cart_subtotal < $minimum_amount  ) {
        // Display an error message
        wc_add_notice( '<strong>' . sprintf( __("A minimum total purchase amount of %s is required to checkout."), wc_price($minimum_amount) ) . '</strong>', 'error' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> If customer update the cart changing quantities or removing items, The behavior will be updated too.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Related answer: [Woocommerce set minimum order for a specific user role](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54892644/woocommerce-set-minimum-order-for-a-specific-user-role/54896822#54896822)

Comment: That works just fine Thank you! though, a closing `<strong>` tag is missing or it may break the style.

Answer (score 4):

```
function disable_checkout_button() { 

    // Set this variable to specify a minimum order value
    $minimum = 50;
    $total = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;
    if( $total < $minimum ){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
        echo '<a style="pointer-events: none !important;" href="#" class="checkout-button button alt wc-forward">Proceed to checkout</a>';
    }  
}

add_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'disable_checkout_button', 1 );
```

Comment: thanks, this is in general working, but if you then increase cart amount, button is still not working.

Comment: I found error in this code. Replace :
$total = WC()->cart->get_cart_subtotal(); 
on
$total = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;

- get Cart Total as number.

Comment: @RuslanNovikov If it's tested ok, you may please modify the answer

Answer (score 0):

```
// Set a minimum dollar amount per order
add_action( 'woocommerce_check_cart_items', 'spyr_set_min_total' );
function spyr_set_min_total() {
    // Only run in the Cart or Checkout pages
    if( is_cart() || is_checkout() ) {
        global $woocommerce;

        // Set minimum cart total
        $minimum_cart_total = 500;

        // Total we are going to be using for the Math
        // This is before taxes and shipping charges
        $total = WC()->cart->subtotal;
        
        // Compare values and add an error is Cart's total
        // happens to be less than the minimum required before checking out.
        // Will display a message along the lines of
        // A Minimum of USD 500 is required before checking out. (Cont. below)
        // Current cart total: USD 6 
        if( $total <= $minimum_cart_total  ) {
            // Display our error message
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( '<strong>A minimum order value of %s is required before checking out.</strong>'
                .'<br />Your current value is: %s',
                wc_price( $minimum_cart_total ),
                wc_price( $total ) ),
            'error' );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).