# WooCommerce: Remove PayPal Express Button in cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, paypal, cart

I want to remove the "Proceed to checkout" buttons in the cart if the cart amount is below 20$.

I found a way to remove the default checkout button with this code:

```
function disable_checkout_button() {

    // Set this variable to specify a minimum order value
    $minimum = 20;
    $total = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;
    if( $total < $minimum ){
        remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'woocommerce_button_proceed_to_checkout', 20 );
    }
}
```

But the PayPal Express Checkout button is still there.
Is there a way to remove that button in the same way?

I didn't found an hook to do it.

EDIT: I read [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-gateway-paypal-express-checkout/issues/533), that the PayPal buttons are added to the cart page using the `woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout` hook.

But adding the following line doesn't do anything for me:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_proceed_to_checkout', 'display_paypal_button', 20 );
```

Comment: Is [setting a minimum order amount](https://woocommerce.com/document/minimum-order-amount/) more what you are after.

Comment: I've already added that code. But it shows only the error message. The user can go to the checkout

Comment: How about https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55038477/set-a-minimum-order-amount-in-woocommerce

Comment: My code above is from an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/55039131/1788961) of that question. It works but it doesn't hide the PayPal button.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'disable_paypal' );
 
function disable_paypal( $available_gateways ) {
$minimum = 20;
if ( WC()->cart->total > $minimum ) {
unset( $available_gateways['ppec_paypal'] );
}
return $available_gateways;
}
```

Check for available payment gateway set the minimum amount and then disable Paypal.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: The if condition is not working here or the whole function?

Comment: the whole function. I've changed `$maximum` to `$minimum` already

Comment: return a static string to check if the function is working well.