# Automatically apply discount to user role if no coupon is applied in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, discount

I have this code below but I want it to be effective only if the user is not using another code, and if the user uses another coupon, then disable this one.

based on *"[Apply a discount for a specific user role in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889136/apply-a-discount-for-a-specific-user-role-in-woocommerce/54890439#54890439)"* answer code, I've been trying to look how to check if there's any coupon but can't figure it out.

```
// Applying conditionally a discount for a specific user role
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'discount_based_on_user_role', 20, 1 );
function discount_based_on_user_role( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return; // Exit

    // Only for 'company' user role
    if ( ! current_user_can('affiliate') )
        return; // Exit

    // Only for 'company' user role
    if ( ! current_user_can('affiliate') )
        return; // Exit

    // HERE define the percentage discount
    $percentage = 15;

    $discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * $percentage / 100;
    // Applying discount
    $cart->add_fee( sprintf( __("Affiliate Discount (%s)", "woocommerce"), $percentage . '%'), -$discount, true );
}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following that will set a custom discount based on specific user role, if there is no applied coupons in cart:

```
// Applying conditionally a discount for a specific user role and no applied coupons
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'discount_based_on_user_role', 20, 1 );
function discount_based_on_user_role( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return; // Exit

    // Only for 'affiliate' user role
    if ( ! current_user_can('affiliate') )
        return; // Exit

    // Only if there is no applied coupons in cart
    if ( ! empty( $cart->get_applied_coupons() ) )
        return; // Exit

    // HERE define the percentage discount
    $percentage = 15;

    $discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * $percentage / 100; // Calculation

    // Applying discount
    $cart->add_fee( sprintf( __("Affiliate Discount (%s)", "woocommerce"), $percentage . '%'), -$discount, true );
}
```

Code goes on *`functions.php`* file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.