# Show possible discount to unlogged users for WooCommerce discount based on user roles

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, user-roles, discount

I used the [Apply a discount for a specific user role in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889136/apply-a-discount-for-a-specific-user-role-in-woocommerce) solution to create two snippets that will give my customers and wholesalers a discount this Black Friday.

However, the discount for customers only shows when they login. Is there a way to display the customer discount before the customer logs in?

```
// Apply Discount for Customer

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'discount_based_on_customer', 20, 1 );
function discount_based_on_customer( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( ! current_user_can('customer') )
        return;

    $percentage = 50;

    $discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * $percentage / 100; // Calculation

    $cart->add_fee( sprintf( __("Black Friday Discount (%s)", "woocommerce"), $percentage . '%'), -$discount, true );
}

// Apply Discount for Wholesaler

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'discount_based_on_wholesaler', 10, 1 );
function discount_based_on_wholesaler( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( ! ( current_user_can('default_wholesaler') || current_user_can('wholesaler-non-vat-registered') ) )
        return;

    $percentage = 10;

    $discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * $percentage / 100; // Calculation

    $cart->add_fee( sprintf( __("Black Friday Reseller Discount (%s)", "woocommerce"), $percentage . '%'), -$discount, true );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, instead of using multiple snippets on the same hook you can merge them in a unique hooked function to handle all required user roles.

Then for unlogged users, you can print a notice on cart and checkout page that will display the discount amount and percentage that user can get if they are logged in (displaying also a login link on the right side of the notice)

[image]

The complete revisited code:

```php
// User roles discount percentage
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'discount_percentage_based_on_user_roles' );
function discount_percentage_based_on_user_roles( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Logged in users only
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $text_domain = 'woocommerce'; // Text domain for translations
        $percentage  = 0;  // Initializing
        $user_obj    = wp_get_current_user(); // Get the WP_User Object

        // 1. Customer user role
        if ( in_array('customer', $user_obj->roles ) ) {
            $percentage = 50;
            $label_text = sprintf( __("Black Friday Discount (%s)", $text_domain), $percentage.'%');
        }

        // 2. Wholesalers users roles
        elseif ( array_intersect( array('default_wholesaler', 'wholesaler-non-vat-registered'), $user_obj->roles ) ) {
            $percentage = 10;
            $label_text = sprintf( __("Black Friday Reseller Discount (%s)", $text_domain), $percentage.'%');
        }

        // THE DISCOUNT
        if ( $percentage > 0 ) {
            $discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * $percentage / 100; // Calculation

            $cart->add_fee( $label_text, -$discount, true ); // Apply calculated discount
        }
    }
}

// For unlogged Users: display a notice with the discount percentage and the loging link (cart and checkout pages)
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_checkout_form', 'discount_percentage_notice_for_unlogged_users' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart_table', 'discount_percentage_notice_for_unlogged_users' );
function discount_percentage_notice_for_unlogged_users() {
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $text_domain = 'woocommerce'; // Text domain for translations
        $percentage  = 50;
        $login_link  = get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'myaccount' ) );
        $login_text  = __("Login / Register", $text_domain);

        wc_print_notice( sprintf(
            __('You could get %s off on Black Friday Discount (%s).%s', $text_domain),
            '<strong>' . wc_price(WC()->cart->subtotal * $percentage / 100) . '</strong>',
            $percentage . '%',
            '<a href="' . $login_link . '" class="button" style="float:right;">' . $login_text . '</a>'
        ), 'notice' );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

Or if you want to apply the discount for "customer" user role to guest users *(unlogged)*, you will use instead this:

```php
// User roles and guests discount percentage
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'discount_percentage_based_on_user_roles' );
function discount_percentage_based_on_user_roles( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
        
    $text_domain = 'woocommerce'; // Text domain for translations
    $percentage  = 0;  // Initializing
    $user_obj    = wp_get_current_user(); // Get the WP_User Object

    // 1. Wholesalers user roles
    if ( array_intersect( array('default_wholesaler', 'wholesaler-non-vat-registered'), $user_obj->roles ) ) {
        $percentage = 10;
        $label_text = sprintf( __("Black Friday Reseller Discount (%s)", $text_domain), $percentage.'%');
    }
    // 2. Customer user role and guest users
    elseif ( in_array('customer', $user_obj->roles ) || ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $percentage = 50;
        $label_text = sprintf( __("Black Friday Discount (%s)", $text_domain), $percentage.'%');
    }

    // THE DISCOUNT
    if ( $percentage > 0 ) {
        $discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * $percentage / 100; // Calculation

        $cart->add_fee( $label_text, -$discount, true ); // Apply calculated discount
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: I really like your first solution. Great way to get more people to create an account and potentially subscribe to your newsletter. Thanks a lot. Also, the $text_domain = 'woocommerce' is new to me. I'll read more about it..