# Show Role Based Discount on Product Page

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have multiple discount tiers on my site, based on user role. After much digging and scratching and a little help from a friend I found some code that applies this discount perfectly on the cart page. Is there a way to also display this on the product page?

We used the code found here - [Apply a discount for a specific user role in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54889136/apply-a-discount-for-a-specific-user-role-in-woocommerce)
Thanks to [LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec).
This is what we are currently using:

// Reseller Discounts
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'discount_based_on_user_role', 20, 1 );
function discount_based_on_user_role( $cart ) {
if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
return; // Exit

```
// Discount for Reseller_45
if ( ! current_user_can('wcwp_reseller_45') )
    return; // Exit

$percentage = 45;

$discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * $percentage / 100; // Calculation

$cart->add_fee( sprintf( __("Discount (%s)", "woocommerce"), $percentage . '%'), -$discount, true );

if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
    return; // Exit

// Discount for Reseller_40
if ( ! current_user_can('wcwp_reseller_40') )
    return; // Exit

$percentage = 40;

$discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * $percentage / 100; // Calculation

$cart->add_fee( sprintf( __("Discount (%s)", "woocommerce"), $percentage . '%'), -$discount, true );

// Discount for Reseller_35
if ( ! current_user_can('wcwp_reseller_35') )
    return; // Exit

$percentage = 35;

$discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * $percentage / 100; // Calculation

$cart->add_fee( sprintf( __("Discount (%s)", "woocommerce"), $percentage . '%'), -$discount, true );

// Discount for Reseller_30
if ( ! current_user_can('wcwp_reseller_30') )
    return; // Exit

$percentage = 30;

$discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * $percentage / 100; // Calculation

$cart->add_fee( sprintf( __("Discount (%s)", "woocommerce"), $percentage . '%'), -$discount, true );

// Discount for Reseller_25
if ( ! current_user_can('wcwp_reseller_25') )
    return; // Exit

$percentage = 25;

$discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * $percentage / 100; // Calculation

$cart->add_fee( sprintf( __("Discount (%s)", "woocommerce"), $percentage . '%'), -$discount, true );

// Discount for Reseller_20
if ( ! current_user_can('wcwp_reseller_20') )
    return; // Exit

$percentage = 20;

$discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * $percentage / 100; // Calculation

$cart->add_fee( sprintf( __("Discount (%s)", "woocommerce"), $percentage . '%'), -$discount, true );

// Discount for Reseller_15
if ( ! current_user_can('wcwp_reseller_15') )
    return; // Exit

$percentage = 15;

$discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * $percentage / 100; // Calculation

$cart->add_fee( sprintf( __("Discount (%s)", "woocommerce"), $percentage . '%'), -$discount, true );

// Discount for Reseller_10
if ( ! current_user_can('wcwp_reseller_10') )
    return; // Exit

$percentage = 10;

$discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * $percentage / 100; // Calculation

$cart->add_fee( sprintf( __("Discount (%s)", "woocommerce"), $percentage . '%'), -$discount, true );
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Update....
I have had to change to coupons in order to integrate with our POS system (Pastel),
So created role based coupons that are auto applied.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).