# Add a fee based on chosen shipping method in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, shipping-method

In WooCommerce, I need to add a fee when user select specific shipping methods.

I have found *"[Add a fee based on shipping method and payment method in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138784/add-a-fee-based-on-shipping-method-and-payment-method-in-woocommerce/52139130#52139130)"* answer, that looks like what I need.

I have tried the code and removed the pieces about payment method which I don't need.

The problem is that when I change the shipping method the fee is not added, looks like that I just keep the old value in the session.

This is my code:

```
// Add a conditional fee
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'add_cod_fee', 20, 1 );
function add_cod_fee( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $chosen_shipping_method_id = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0];

    var_dump($chosen_shipping_method_id); die;

    switch($chosen_shipping_method_id){
        case 'flat_rate:3': {
            $fee_text = __( "Spese per ritiro", "woocommerce" );
            $cart->add_fee( $fee_text, 12, false );
            break;
        }
        case 'flat_rate:4': {
            $fee_text = __( "Spese per consegna a domicilio", "woocommerce" );
            $cart->add_fee( $fee_text, 24, false );
            break;
        }

    }
}

// Refresh checkout on payment method change
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'refresh_checkout_script' );
function refresh_checkout_script() {
    // Only on checkout page
    if( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url('order-received') ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        // On payment method change
        $('form.woocommerce-checkout').on( 'change', '.shipping_method', function(){
            // Refresh checkout
            $('body').trigger('update_checkout');
        });
    })
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

It just keep the old value in `$chosen_shipping_method_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works nicely if you comment `var_dump($chosen_shipping_method_id); die;`. Also the jQuery script **is not needed** as it was for payment methods that doesn't update checkout by default.

So there is something else that is making trouble in your case.

Now I have revisited a bit your code *(it will work too)*:

```
// Add a conditional fee
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'flat_rate_based_fee', 20, 1 );
function flat_rate_based_fee( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $chosen_shipping_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );

    if( in_array( 'flat_rate:3', $chosen_shipping_methods ) ) {
        $fee = array( 'text' => __( "Spese per ritiro", "woocommerce" ), 'amount' => 12 );
    } elseif ( in_array( 'flat_rate:4', $chosen_shipping_methods ) ) {
        $fee = array( 'text' => __( "Spese per consegna a domicilio", "woocommerce" ), 'amount' => 24 );
    }

    if( isset($fee) ) {
        $cart->add_fee( $fee['text'], $fee['amount'], false );
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).

Tested and work *(on Woocommerce 3.5.x and 3.6.x)*. See it [working live on this test server](https://www.cbleu.net/sites/woo/shop/).

Comment: ok my problem was using that code with the subscription plugin, it added the fee to the weekly subscription instead of the order.
I have changed `$cart->add_fee` with `WC()->cart->add_fee` and now it works

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Good one. How to add/remove the price on the method itself instead of using add_fee?