# Woocommerce change total price depending payment methods

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change total price depending payment method in checkout page , i have two payments method 
if the customer select Cash on delivery Total price become Total * 0.015 + Total
Else the Total price remains unchanged

Comment: Like this Total * 0.015 + Total OR  Total * 0.015 = Total  ???

Comment: Below Answer code is work like Total * 0.015 = Total.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add a fee based on shipping method and payment method in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52138784/add-a-fee-based-on-shipping-method-and-payment-method-in-woocommerce)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file. This code is tested and works.**

> All payment methods are only available on Checkout page.

```
add_action('woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees','custom_handling_fee',10,1);
function custom_handling_fee($cart){
    if(is_admin() && ! defined('DOING_AJAX'))
        return;
    if('cod' === WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method')){
        $extra_cost = 0.015;
        $cart_total = $cart->cart_contents_total; 
        $fee = $cart_total * $extra_cost;
        if($fee != 0)
        $cart->add_fee('COD Charge',$fee,true);
    }
}
```

> You will need the following to refresh checkout on payment method change, to get it work:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer','custom_checkout_jqscript');
function custom_checkout_jqscript(){
    if(is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url()):
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name="payment_method"]', function(){
            $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Hello, i want increase price with 8% and not work.

`code`$extra_cost = 0.015; - old
$extra_cost =8%; - this is corect??`code`

Comment: You can use this $extra_cost = 0.08;