# Local pickup shipping option custom percentage discount in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, discount, shipping-method

My WooCommerce checkout page gives some shipping options:

- Flat Rate (costs money)
- Local Pickup (free).

How can I give a 5% discount on total order cost if a customer chooses Local Pickup shipping method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following code will add a discount of 5% to cart subtotal for **Local Pickup** chosen shipping method:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_discount_for_pickup_shipping_method', 10, 1 );
function custom_discount_for_pickup_shipping_method( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    $percentage = 5; // <=== Discount percentage

    $chosen_shipping_method_id = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0];
    $chosen_shipping_method    = explode(':', $chosen_shipping_method_id)[0];

    // Only for Local pickup chosen shipping method
    if ( strpos( $chosen_shipping_method_id, 'local_pickup' ) !== false ) {
        // Calculate the discount
        $discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * $percentage / 100;
        // Add the discount
        $cart->add_fee( __('Pickup discount') . ' (' . $percentage . '%)', -$discount );
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

> To refresh checkout "order review" section on payment methods change see: 
> [Add fee based on specific payment methods in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382278/add-fee-based-on-specific-payment-methods-in-woocommerce/38384483#38384483)

[image]