# Local pickup custom percentage discount in WooCommerce checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, discount, shipping-method

I am using [Local pickup shipping option custom percentage discount in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52630355/local-pickup-shipping-option-custom-percentage-discount-in-woocommerce/52631612#52631612)  answer code to make local pickup discount of 2% on Woocommerce. So people who choose to pickup their order get a discount on their total amount.
This code is great, but I would like to hide it on cart page, and to only show up on the checkout page. Now it shows on both pages.

I tried to change `$cart` to `$checkout` and I deleted rule 15 and 16 but that won't work unfortunately. Does anyone point me on the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make it active only on checkout page, use the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_discount_for_pickup_shipping_method', 10, 1 );
function custom_discount_for_pickup_shipping_method( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    // Only on checkout page
    if ( is_checkout() ) {
    
        $percentage = 2; // <=== Discount percentage
    
        $chosen_shipping_method_id = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' )[0];
        $chosen_shipping_method    = explode(':', $chosen_shipping_method_id)[0];
    
        // Only for Local pickup chosen shipping method
        if ( strpos( $chosen_shipping_method_id, 'local_pickup' ) !== false ) {
            // Calculate the discount
            $discount = $cart->get_subtotal() * $percentage / 100;
            // Add the discount
            $cart->add_fee( __('Pickup discount') . ' (' . $percentage . '%)', -$discount );
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.