# Check WooCommerce User Role and Payment Gateway and if they match - Apply fee

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, hook-woocommerce

I'm struggling with applying a fee for an array of user roles if and when a specific payment gateway is selected.

The code I've written works fine if I do not check the user role, but once I try and do that, it does not.

I've removed (commented) the user role `if` statement in the code and I'm asking for help making it work.

I need to check if the user role match my `array` and if it does, check the payment gateway. If the payment gateway match too, apply the fee.

This is my code:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_fee', 20, 1 );
function custom_fee ($cart){

    if (is_admin() && !defined('DOING_AJAX')) return;

    if (!is_user_logged_in()) return;

    if (!is_checkout() && !is_wc_endpoint_url()) return;

    $customer_role = wp_get_current_user();
    $roles_to_check = array( 'vendor', 'external' );
    $payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');

        // if (!in_array($roles_to_check, $customer_role->roles)) return;

    if ('bacs' == $payment_method){
        $payment_fee = $cart->subtotal * 0.05;
            $cart->add_fee( 'Payment Fee', $payment_fee, true );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the following, explanation with comments added in the code

Conditions that must be met in this code are:

- only for certain user roles
- checks on payment method

```php
function custom_fee( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;
    
    if ( ! ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) )
        return; // Only checkout page
    
    if ( ! is_user_logged_in())
        return;

    // Get current WP_User Object
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    
    // User roles
    $roles = ( array ) $user->roles;

    // Roles to check
    $roles_to_check = array( 'vendor', 'external', 'administrator' );
    
    // Compare
    $compare = array_diff( $roles, $roles_to_check );

    // Result is empty
    if ( empty ( $compare ) ) {
        // Payment method
        $payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');

        // Condition equal to
        if ( $payment_method == 'bacs' ) { 
            // Calculate
            $payment_fee = $cart->subtotal * 0.05;

            // Add fee
            $cart->add_fee( 'Payment Fee', $payment_fee, true );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_fee', 10, 1 );
```

---

**EDIT**

To complete my answer, see the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63305709/11987538) from @[LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3730754/loictheaztec)

Comment: How do you get this to work on the "check,-out/order-pay"?

Answer (score 1):

The answer of @7uc1f3r is good, **but something important is missing from** it.

In WooCommerce checkout when choosing a payment method, checkout totals are not refreshed. So  something additional is required to refresh checkout "order review" section:

```
// jQuery - Update checkout on payment method change
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_jquery_script' );
function custom_checkout_jquery_script() {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name="payment_method"]', function(){
            $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Related: [Add fee based on specific payment methods in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382278/add-fee-based-on-specific-payment-methods-in-woocommerce/38384483#38384483)