# WooCommerce COD charges based on cart amount

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, payment-method

I want to charge extra fee if any one select COD as payment method.

Suppose if the cart amount is 10 to 1000 INR COD charges will be RS.50/- and 1001 to 2000 then COD charges will be RS.100- and so on.

I am using "*[Add fee for Cash on delivery payment method (cod) in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382278/add-fee-for-cash-on-delivery-payment-method-cod-in-woocommerce/38384483#38384483)*" answer code, and I need some more customizations.

Comment: StackOverFlow is not a free coding service and we expect you to provide in your question your code attempt…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a PHP `switch` statement that takes the cart subtotal rounded up to the nearest power of 1000, and then base your fee of that. So for instance a subtotal of anything between 1001 and 2000 (including 2000) will be rounded to 2000. Which will be interpreted by the switch statement and a fee of 100 will be assigned.

The default in the switch statement will take care of anything higher than any of the cases you add to it.

```
// Add a custom fee based on cart subtotal
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'custom_cod_fee', 10, 1 );
function custom_cod_fee ( $cart ) {

    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( 'cod' === WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method') ) {

        switch ( ceil( $cart->subtotal / 1000 ) * 1000  ) {
            case "1000": // 0 to 1000
                $fee = 50;
                break;
            case "2000": // 1001 to 2000
                $fee = 100;
                break;
            case "3000": // 2001 to 3000
                $fee = 150;
                break;
            case "4000": // 3001 to 4000
                $fee = 200;
                break;
            case "5000": // 4001 to 5000
                $fee = 250;
                break;
            default: // anything higher, no fee
                $fee = '';
        }

        if ( !empty( $fee ) ) $cart->add_fee( 'COD Fee', $fee, true );
    }
}
```

And obviously you would need the code that will update the checkout if you change payment gateways:

```
// jQuery - Update checkout on methode payment change
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_jqscript' );
function custom_checkout_jqscript() {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name="payment_method"]', function(){
            $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot brother. It's working and I need one more help which is If the cart sub total is more than 5000 INR then there will be no charges for the COD payment method

Comment: No problem, edited my answer.