# Add fee based on payment methods and cart items total in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-method, fee

I have a plugin installed -> "Payment Gateway Based Fees and Discounts for WooCommerce" which helped me add two fees:

- 14,99 delivery fee on Card Payment
- 19,99 delivery fee on Cash on delivery

The problem is that I want to give free delivery if someone buys over 300 let's say. So i have to remove the extra fees
This is something that I've tried, but nothing happend:

```
function woo_remove_cart_fee() {

  $cart_items_total = WC()->cart->get_cart_contents_total();

    if ( $cart_items_total > 300 ) {
        $fees = 0 ;     
   } 

add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'woo_add_remove_fee' );
```

Any ideas?
Or any ideas on how to have both the Gateway fees and the free shipping over a limit?

Thanks.

Comment: Or you use the plugin, or you use custom code which allow more customizations… Adding fees as this plugin does, is something very easy with some custom code. See [all related threads using `woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees) in StackOverFlow.

Comment: I have answered your question… Any feed back on the answer below will be highly appreciated please.

Comment: I know this is a late reply, but this may help someone. The plugin now has the options of "Minimum Cart Amount" and "Maximum Cart Amount". The Max Cart amount option will waive off all the fees that are added by the plugin if the order total goes above that amount.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't delete fees added by a plugin based on cart items total mount.

As your plugin doesn't handle a min  or max cart amount condition, disable the fees first from it *(or disable the plugin)* and use instead the following:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'fee_based_on_payment_method_and_total' );
function fee_based_on_payment_method_and_total( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined('DOING_AJAX') )
        return;
        
    $threshold_amount  = 300; // Total amount to reach for no fees
    
    $payment_method_id = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');
    $cart_items_total  = $cart->get_cart_contents_total();

    if ( $cart_items_total < $threshold_amount ) {
        // For cash on delivery "COD"
        if ( $payment_method_id === 'cod' ) {
            $fee = 14.99;
            $text = __("Fee");
        } 
        // For credit cards (other payment gateways than "COD", "BACS" or "CHEQUE"
        elseif ( ! in_array( $payment_method_id, ['bacs', 'cheque'] ) ) {
            $fee = 19.99;
            $text = __("Fee");
        }
    }
    
    if( isset($fee) && $fee > 0 ) {
        $cart->add_fee( $text, $fee, false ); // To make fee taxable change "false" to "true"
    }
}
```

And the following code to refresh data on payment method change:

```
// jQuery - Update checkout on payment method change
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'custom_checkout_jquery_script' );
function custom_checkout_jquery_script() {
    if ( is_checkout() && ! is_wc_endpoint_url() ) :
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( function($){
        $('form.checkout').on('change', 'input[name="payment_method"]', function(){
            $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

related: [Add fee based on specific payment methods in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382278/add-fee-based-on-specific-payment-methods-in-woocommerce/38384483#38384483)