# Update total Woocommerce Checkout based on payment method

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a problem when I try to update woocommerce total based on payment method on checkout page. In my case I need to apply a discount if customer select paypal or credit card.
The strange thing is that the most of times the code works corrrectly but for about 20-25% of order it doesn't work.

This is my code to trigger the update:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'refresh_payment_methods',  20, 1  );
function refresh_payment_methods() {
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      (function($){
        $( 'form.checkout' ).on( 'change', 'input[name^="payment_method"]', function() {
          $('body').trigger('update_checkout'); 
        });  
      });
    </script>
<?php } ?>
```

This is the code that manage the discount:

```
/* APPLY DISCOUNT BASED ON PAYMENT METHOD */ 
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review', 'payment_method_discount', 10, 2); 
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'payment_method_discount', 20, 1 );
function payment_method_discount( $cart_object ) {

    if ( is_admin() && !defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) return;

    foreach($cart_object->cart_contents as $cart_item_id => $cart_item) {
      $riepilogo = json_decode(stripslashes($cart_item['_dettagli_noleggio']));
      $payment_method_arr = array('ppcp-gateway' ,'axepta');
        
        $chosen_payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method'); 

            
        if(in_array($chosen_payment_method, $payment_method_arr)) {             
          $discount = number_format( ($riepilogo->noleggio->prezzo_noleggio / 100) * $percent , 2);
          WC()->cart->add_fee( 'Sconto pagamento online', 0 - $discount );
      
          $riepilogo->noleggio->prezzo_noleggio_scontato = number_format( $riepilogo->noleggio->prezzo_noleggio - $discount , 2, '.','');
          $riepilogo->noleggio->prezzo_totale_scontato = number_format( $riepilogo->noleggio->prezzo_noleggio_scontato + $riepilogo->noleggio->prezzo_accessori + $riepilogo->noleggio->prezzo_assicurazione, 2, '.','');
          $cart_object->cart_contents[$cart_item_id]['_dettagli_noleggio'] = json_encode($riepilogo);

        }else{
           
          $fees = WC()->cart->get_fees();
          foreach ($fees as $key => $fee) {
            unset($fees[$key]);
          }
          WC()->cart->fees_api()->set_fees($fees);   

           $riepilogo->noleggio->prezzo_noleggio_scontato = "";
           $riepilogo->noleggio->prezzo_totale = number_format( $riepilogo->noleggio->prezzo_noleggio + $riepilogo->noleggio->prezzo_accessori + $riepilogo->noleggio->prezzo_assicurazione, 2,'.','');
           $riepilogo->noleggio->prezzo_totale_scontato = ''; 
           $cart_object->cart_contents[$cart_item_id]['_dettagli_noleggio'] = json_encode($riepilogo);
          
        }    
    }       
}
```

I think the cause of the problem is related to the saving times in the database. When I go on paypal or credit card page I get the full price instead of the discounted value.

Any suggest or best approach to do it?

Answer (score 0):

First, in your code, the `$percent` variable is not defined. Your question is not really clear (missing context) and your code is not testable.

What is behind `$cart_item['_dettagli_noleggio']` and how do you set it?

Based [on this answer code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382278/add-fee-based-on-specific-payment-methods-in-woocommerce/38384483#38384483), try the following revised and simplified code:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_init', 'payment_method_change_trigger_update_checkout_js' );
function payment_method_change_trigger_update_checkout_js() {
    wc_enqueue_js("$('form.checkout').on( 'change', 'input[name=payment_method]', function(){
        $(document.body).trigger('update_checkout');
    });");
}


add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'payment_method_discount', 20, 1 );
function payment_method_discount( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && !defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) 
        return;

    $percent         = 10; // HERE define the percentage
    $payment_methods = array('ppcp-gateway' ,'axepta'); // HERE define the allowed payment IDs
    $chosen_payment  = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method'); 
    $discount        = 0; // Initializing

    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $item_key => $item ) {
        if ( isset($item['_dettagli_noleggio']) && in_array($chosen_payment, $payment_methods) ) {
            $rent_data  = json_decode(stripslashes($item['_dettagli_noleggio']));      
            $discount  -= number_format( ($rent_data->noleggio->prezzo_noleggio / 100) * $percent , 2);
        }
    }

    if ( $discount < 0 ) {
        $cart->add_fee( 'Sconto pagamento online', $discount );
    }     
}
```

Or for multiple separated discounts, replace the 2nd function with:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_calculate_fees', 'payment_method_discount', 20, 1 );
function payment_method_discount( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && !defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) ) 
        return;

    $percent         = 10; // HERE define the percentage
    $payment_methods = array('ppcp-gateway' ,'axepta'); // HERE define the allowed payment IDs
    $chosen_payment  = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method'); 

    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $item_key => $item ) {
        if ( isset($item['_dettagli_noleggio']) && in_array($chosen_payment, $payment_methods) ) {
            $rent_data  = json_decode(stripslashes($item['_dettagli_noleggio']));      
            $discount   = number_format( ($rent_data->noleggio->prezzo_noleggio / 100) * $percent , 2);
            $cart->add_fee( 'Sconto pagamento online', -$discount );
        }
    }    
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). It could work.